# Python: checking user response to raw_input()

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to get the user to put in a specific word.

my code:

```
import os

os.system("clear")

def get_answer():
    print "\nWould you like to 'hit', 'stick', 'double' down or 'split'?"
    x = raw_input('> ')
    answers = ['hit', 'stick', 'double', 'split']
    y = [i for i in answers if i in x]
    if y == []:
        get_answer()
    print y
    # exit(0)
    return y

def foo():
    a = get_answer()
    print a

foo()
```

here's my output if I answer 'hit' the first time;

```
Would you like to 'hit', 'stick', 'double' down or 'split'?
> hit 
['hit']
['hit']
```

here's my output if I type 'blah' the fist time and then 'hit':

```
Would you like to 'hit', 'stick', 'double' down or 'split'?
> blah

Would you like to 'hit', 'stick', 'double' down or 'split'?
> hit
['hit']
[]
[]
```

I don't even really know how to research this.  Is it a simple syntax error or is there a deeper issue I just don't understand?  I'd love to know how to do this properly.

Comment: the [`cmd`](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) module is probably what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to simply test `if x in answers`, which checks to see if the input is one of the elements in `answers`.

Also, since you are using recursion to get the user's input, inputting an incorrect value puts another `get_answer()` call on the stack. The result is that while the innermost `get_answer` gets valid input, the outer `get_answer` call(s) continue executing, resulting in the weird output you see.

For example, in your second case, `['hit']` is generated by the innermost call's `print y`, the first `[]` is generated by the outer call's `print y` (since the inner `get_answer` finishes), and the last `[]` is generated by `print a` in `foo()` (since the outer `get_answer` returns `[]`).

What you probably want to do instead is either (a) change the `get_answer` call to `return get_answer()` so that the innermost call's value is sent back up the stack, or (b) change the `get_answer` call to a loop, and break out when you get a good answer.

Assuming you're trying to get the user to input exactly one of the options, here's how you could structure the code to use a loop instead of recursion:

```
def get_answer():
    answers = ['hit', 'stick', 'double', 'split']
    while True:
        print "\nWould you like to 'hit', 'stick', 'double' down or 'split'?"
        answer = raw_input('> ')
        if answer in answers:
            return answer

print get_answer()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer!  However, a code example would be greatly appreciated, as I've tried to employ your suggestion and i'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a bit more fundamental. In the `get_answer()` function, you [recurse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) by calling the function from within itself:

```
if y == []:
    get_answer()
```

While this works, I doubt it's your intended behavior. You have to call `get_answer()` outside of `get_answer()` in order to prompt for values nicely.

Anyways, here's how I would structure your code:

```
def get_answer(question, answers):
    response = raw_input(question)

    while response not in answers:
        response = raw_input(question)

    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    question = "Would you like to 'hit', 'stick', 'double' down or 'split'?\n> "
    answers = ['hit', 'stick', 'double', 'split']

    print get_answer(question, answers)
```

Comment: Well, not exactly true. If you do 'if y == []: return get_answer()' it actually works fine (unless the user inputs the wrong thing 1000 times and gets a stack overflow...)

Comment: If a function reaches the maximum recursion depth, Python just throws a `RuntimeError`. I don't recommend using recursion in this case because it isn't needed.